# Why my appbottombar is taking my whole layout height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar

I am using this code in my xml layout I added my layout below and some images

```
 ......

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/notes_container_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

       .......
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_note_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:hideOnScroll="false"
            app:menu="@menu/appbar_menu"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

and the height of the BottomAppbar is taking my whole layout as shown in the image [image]

and it should look like this image [image]

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: I updated my post to include the image

Comment: Post the entire layout

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not in the dimension of the `BottomAppBar`.
Check your parent layout dimension or position:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/notes_container_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

The `BottomAppBar` has the right height but the `CoordinatorLayout` uses `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.
Change the height of the `CoordinatorLayout` or use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` in your `CoordinatorLayout`.

[image]